# Can I use FindFirstChangeNotification to notify on files created on a network drive?

Tags: delphi, networking, filesystemwatcher

I need to detect a file being created on a NAS drive. The system that needs to be notified is running Windows.  I first tried [Watch 4 Folder 2.5](http://Watch%204%20Folder%202.5%20-%20Free%20Version) but it did not work. The author reports it does not support network drives.
So I looked for ways to develop my own utility. I found the [ATFileNotification Component](http://torry.net/pages.php?id=252) for Delphi.

It can detect changes if the Windows machine that is running the notify utility creates or deletes the file on the network share. However, if the file is created by any other machine on the network, the utility does not notify.

The ATFileNotification component encapsulates the Win32 FindFirstChangeNotification function.  Is the inability to detect changes on a remote drive not caused by the system where it is running a fundamental shortcoming of FindFirstChangeNotification, or is there some type of parameter I need to set or other workaround?

If FindFirstChangeNotification is unable to perform this task, is there any method to detect remote files other than polling the remote directory on a timer?

Comment: This type of behaviour typically needs to be supported by the server.  I presume the NAS is a linux box running samba?  The default for samba is to support change notifications at a 60 second interval, iirc.  These settings can be changed in smb.conf.  This is how, for example, windows explorer will refresh a directory to show a new file in a specific networked resource location when that location is currently being shown in explorer.

Comment: J - good point. I did not wait that long to see if the notification would ever arrive.  I got it instantly on delete. You are correct, the notification does come after a delay, up to a minute, but faster sometimes.